# Facebook won't let me as sole admin post or comment in my group

Tags: facebook

I'm still a member, still sole admin, have posted nothing breaking the rules. I can like a post or comment, but Facebook will not allow me to make a post or comment (including on a post that I made). I have refreshed the page (multiple times), and logged out & back on.

I can still post and comment on my personal page and on my biz page, but not in the group that I run. I reported the problem to Facebook and got an automated answer.

Comment: So what’s the question?

Comment: Sorry if I used improper format, Alex! The question is: What can I do to be able to make posts & comments again on a FB group of which I am sole Admin, since FB is blocking me from doing this?

Comment: The problem seems to have resolved itself. :) I just heard that this is an ongoing problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was introduced by update 2.3 pushed march 25th. It was due to the introduction of the `user_posts` permission involving post permissions on pages and was hotfixed within the day of the update. A good practice in troubleshooting is to always refer to the changelog when you encounter a bug. Usually bugs like this show up and are squashed within hours of the patch due to the massive community that facebook is.